# Problem with bold font of capital greek letters

Tags: math-mode, bold, greek, boldmath

My tex file is as follows. It prints greek letters in small and capital format. When I print a capital greek letter, it automatically becomes bold and when I use a math bold capital greek letter it turns into a black filled block. How to turn this template into normal mode?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

aaaaaa

\begin{align}
\mathbf T \mathbf \Phi\\
\mathbf U \mathbf \Pi \\
\mathbf T \mathbf \phi\\
\mathbf U \mathbf \pi \\
\mathbf T A \Phi\\
\mathbf U A \Pi
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: greek bold font block]

The minimal additional files are

[PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/blob/master/Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls)

[glyphtounicode.tex](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/blob/master/Classes/glyphtounicode.tex)

Comment: Use \boldsymbol for Greek letters (and also for Latin characters)

Comment: @marmot, thanks. However, in this template using `\boldsymbol` changes nothing. The template decides if a letter should be bold or not. No matter what you tell latex.

Comment: This is a font issue -- `times` as font option does not provide bold uppercase greek letters, apparently

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. Thanks. How can I disable all font overwriting by this template?

Comment: i'm not familiar with the document class used, but i think the problem is caused by the use of the option `times`, which causes the times fonts to be used, at least for the latin letters.  the bold caps in the math are times, not computer modern.  since there are a number of different ways that math fonts can be set up, it's not easy to know how this document class is doing that without examining the code, and i don't have access to the class file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It's one of those templates for 'thesis' documents Johannes B. is complaining about  (all the time) -- do I have to say more? ;-)

Comment: @ar2015: Removing `times` enforces the `fourier` fonts -- everything seems to be alright then. By the way: `times` is no really nice font, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- i can recognize its nature by the name.  (but i still don't have access to it; it's not useful to me, and to examine it, i'd have to retrieve it from wherever, and i'd rather not do that on my laptop.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, The code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/archive/master.zip)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not to mention the fact that you'd never know if you had the same version as the OP.

Comment: @OP Sorry, but I only download `.zip` files if I need to and at least have no reason to distrust the source. I don't have positive reason to distrust you or this `.zip`, but I have no need to download it. Asking people to download `zip`s from unknown sources is optimistic. Somebody may risk it for you, but you shouldn't count on it. Especially since the best advise anybody can give you is not to use it in the first place.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should not use a non-default copy of `glyphtounicode.tex`. If the class needs a modified copy, it should rename it and use the renamed version.

Comment: @cfr, I am not sure how much you are familiar with `github`. The source code is visible to everybody [here](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/).

Comment: Perhaps, but you linked to a `.zip`.

Comment: @cfr, in the question I referred to the source code, however some people mentioned that they don't have access to the class file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton said she doesn't have access to it because she would have to retrieve it and doesn't want to. How would providing a `.zip` file help?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Of course the purpose of the class is pretty obvious, but that was not the point of my remark. I mentioned the word 'template', that's the crucial point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

aaaaaa

\begin{align}
\mathbf T \bm \Phi\\
\mathbf U \bm \Pi \\
\mathbf T \bm \phi\\
\mathbf U \bm \pi \\
\mathbf T A \Phi\\
\mathbf U A \Pi
\end{align}

\end{document}
```